# How to get controls present in tree view item on context menu click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to rename and delete item(stack panel) from the tree view item
My XAML structure as follows

```
<TreeViewItem Name="trvMyCollections" Header="MY COLLECTIONS" 
              Foreground="#8A949E" Background="#DCE1E7" >
    <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="New Collection" Name="mniNewCollection"
                      Click="mniNewCollection_Click"></MenuItem>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="Rename" Name="mniRenameCollection"
                      Click="mniRenameCollection_Click"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Move to Trash" Name="mniMoveToThrash"
                      Click="mniMoveToThrash_Click"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
</TreeViewItem>
```

I am programatically adding image and textbox to above treeview item as follows

```
private void CreateCollectionUI(string collectionId, string collectionName)
{
    StackPanel StackPanelCollection = new StackPanel();
    StackPanelCollection.Width = 290;
    StackPanelCollection.Height = 28;
    StackPanelCollection.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#DCE1E7"));
    StackPanelCollection.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    StackPanelCollection.Margin = new Thickness(-39, 0, 0, 0);

    Image imgCollectionImage = new Image();
    imgCollectionImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/component/Resources/Images/folder.png"));
    imgCollectionImage.Margin = new Thickness(38, 0, 0, 0);
    imgCollectionImage.Height = 23;
    imgCollectionImage.Width = 23;
    imgCollectionImage.Name = string.Concat("img", collectionId);
    StackPanelCollection.Children.Add(imgCollectionImage);

    TextBox txbxCollectionName = new TextBox();
    txbxCollectionName.Text = collectionName;
    txbxCollectionName.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    txbxCollectionName.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
    txbxCollectionName.IsReadOnly = true;
    txbxCollectionName.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    txbxCollectionName.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    txbxCollectionName.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    txbxCollectionName.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
    txbxCollectionName.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txbxCollectionName_LostFocus);
    txbxCollectionName.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(StackPanelCollection_MouseDown);
    StackPanelCollection.Children.Add(txbxCollectionName);
    txbxCollectionName.Tag = collectionId;
    StackPanelCollection.Name = string.Concat("stpnlCollection", collectionId);
    StackPanelCollection.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(StackPanelCollection_MouseDown);
    trvMyCollections.Items.Add(StackPanelCollection);
}
```

How to remove programatically added stack panel from tree view item(on delete operation)?

for rename functionality I have to do the textbox property readonly false,

How can I get the each stack panel of treeview item and control present in each stack panel on rename click of context menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method like this:

```
string panelName = string.Concat("stpnlCollection", collectionId);
StackPanel panel = trvMyCollections.FindName(panelName) as StackPanel;

if (panel != null)
{
   //do your stuff, for example, delete:
   trvMyCollections.Items.Remove(panel);
}
```

Or you can use [`TreeView.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx) to get selected item.